# How to concatenate two integers into a string without losing precision?

Tags: sql, numbers

I have the following table:

| id | BigNumber | SmallNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 200 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 25 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | 50 |

The big number and small number in each row will be combined to make one number. The big number will  go to the left of the decimal point, and the small number  go to the right of the decimal point. (e.g. Row 1 makes 1.100) I want to make a query that returns the largest number possible with these rules. I also don't want any kind of rounding (e.g. Row 1 should make 1.100 and not 1.1). With the data above, the query should return 3.50.

Here is the query I came up with

```
select max(cast(concat(big_number,'.',small_number) as decimal)) from runs;
```

The query returns 4. I know that I can do something like decimal(3,2), but the numbers will always be different depending on how many digits big number and small number have. How can I make the query always return the correct string representation of the number with the correct precision?

Comment: which database system are you using. Also trailing 0 are often reduced, so why do you want the zeros in the first place, whe you need then to calculate you don't need them, if they are only to display keep them as string

Comment: 1.1 is not a rounded version of 1.100, it's literally the same number

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please add an appropriate tag to your question. Also, what input values would yield a result of 1.01 or 1.001? Is your input data a character type instead of a number type, so that it could store leading zeros like "01" or "001"?  (This sounds like a really bad homework exercise involving a horrible data model. The only save would be if your instructor gave you this exercise with the intent to teach you to never ever design data like this for the rest of your professional career.)

Comment: Why can't you just do `select top 1 * from runs order by cast(big_number as int) desc, cast(small_number as int) desc;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `LPAD` to maintain 0 padding on small number. Here is the sample code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(big_number, '.', LPAD(small_number, LENGTH(small_number), '0')) AS concatenated_number
FROM runs
ORDER BY CAST(CONCAT(big_number, '.', LPAD(small_number, LENGTH(small_number), '0')) AS DECIMAL) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Here is the sample output :

| concatenated_number |
| --- |
| 3.50 |

Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mo1NsZND)

**UPDATE:**

In case you have data `9,5`, `9,55` and `9.555` , you can check with this code instead code above

```
SELECT CONCAT(big_number, '.', LPAD(small_number, LENGTH(small_number), '0')) AS concatenated_number
FROM runs
WHERE CONCAT(big_number, '.', LPAD(small_number, LENGTH(small_number), '0')) = (
    SELECT MAX(CAST(CONCAT(big_number, '.', LPAD(small_number, LENGTH(small_number), '0')) AS FLOAT))
    FROM runs
);
```

This code should make more numerically stable even you reorder the input data.

Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/fQ-4XV7H)

The `LPAD` function is used to ensure that the `small_number` part of the concatenated value has additional zeros if needed. For example, when the `small_number` is 55, which doesn't require extra padding, `LPAD` doesn't modify it; it remains as 55. However, when the small_number is `50`, LPAD adds an additional zero, resulting in `.50` instead of `.5`. Its purpose is to maintain consistency in the format of the concatenated number.

Comment: The above solution is not numerically stable. If you add `(9, 5), (9, 55), (9, 555)` to the data, the result is `9.5` instead of `9.555`.  The results change if you reorder the input data. And what is the purpose of `LPAD` if the requested length is the same as the source length?

Comment: I think you went from a truncated value compare to a text compare. Try adding `(10, 5), (10, 55), (10, 555)`. Perhaps a cast to FLOAT instead of DECIMAL (aka DECIMAL(10,0)) would work.

Comment: Thank. Added all that information on my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `cast` inside `order by`:

```
select concat(big_number, '.', small_number) as concatenated
from t
order by cast(concat(big_number, '.', small_number) as decimal(20, 10)) desc
limit 1
```